# How to Conduct a Three-step Latent Profile Analysis

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to perform a three-step Latent Profile Analysis (LPA) - including covariates and distal outcomes, in Rstudio, but haven't found yet a package to perform it and a reviewer asked to apply this three step in my LPA. I found few information but it only related related to LCA.

I run a LPA using tidy LPA package:

```
lPAm1 <- eficpsicLPA[1:464, ] %>%
  select(zTeachers, zStudents, zFamily, zCommunity) %>%
  estimate_profiles(3)
```

The next step would be, I think, extracting the probabilities for each profile, combining it to the main dataset and then test the effects of covariates and on the distal outcomes, but I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone knows a straightforward package to do a three step LPA?

Comment: Perhaps of help https://willhipson.netlify.app/post/latent-profile/latent-profile/